# In Sharepoint 2013: Ensure all team members see "locked for editing" when attempting to edit file in use?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am working on a file & I see "locked for editing" whenever others are using this file.

Sometimes my team-members don't get this notification & lose their work.  I need to ensure that ALL team-members receive this notification.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are the users editing the file? Are they editing in browser, or have they opened the SharePoint library in Windows Explorer? Also, what file types are they editing - I believe only Microsoft Office files have the ability to notify when the file is in use for editing...

Comment: Sorry for the delay - we are editing in the browser by clicking on the link that brings up the excel file, and we then edit it from there?

Comment: What browser are the people having the problem using?

Comment: IE explorer is the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is the library configured for check in and out? By default is is not and multiple people can make edits. Even if this is not enabled you may see this message if someone is editing it online and someone is editing in the desktop client, or of course if they have manually checked it out.

This can cause confusion - so if you want to force the system to only recognize one user at a time, change the library setting to require check in/out for editing.